# How to run a query in Laravel 4 using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have read the documentation but I can't quite figure out how to run the following query in Laravel 4

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    acl a,
    routes r
WHERE
    (a.user_id = 1 OR
     a.group_id IN(SELECT group_id FROM user_group_junction WHERE user_id = 1)) AND
     r.route = 'protected' AND
     a.routes_id = r.id;
```

So how would I run the query in Laravel 4 using eloquent?

Yes each table has a model and relationships are defined

Based on my selected answer the following is what I came up with (And works)

```
Acls::join('routes','routes.id','=','acl.routes_id')
                ->where('routes.route','=','protected')
                ->Where(function($in_parenthesis) use($user_id){
                    $in_parenthesis->whereIn('acl.group_id',function($where_in) use($user_id){
                            $where_in->select('group_id')
                                ->from('user_group_junction')
                                ->where('user_id','=',$user_id);
                            })
                    ->orWhere('acl.user_id','=',$user_id);
                })
                ->count();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods called on Eloquent models pass through to the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` class, which itself extends from the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` class. This means that all the things you can do with the [query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries), you can also do with Eloquent models. The exception being that you don't need to define the table.

So for example if you wanted to perform a join and a where like you've done above, you would just do:

```
$query = Acl::join('routes', 'acl.routes_id', '=', 'routes.id')
             ->where('routes.route', '=', 'protected');

$results = $query->get();
```

Obviously this isn't your whole query, but you can figure out the rest.